# How to pass Map<String,List<String>> in application.properties spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have to configure below key value pair in my **application.yml** file  where key will be a string and value will be List of

```
Eg: Map<String,List<String>> : How this we should configure in application.yml:



 movement    = accountId,positionId,accountName
 transaction = transctionId,transctionName,transctionDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following attribute in your Configuration class:

```java
private Map<String,List<String>> config;
```

You could achieve this with the following configuration in `application.yml`:

```yaml
config:
  movement:
   - accountId
   - positionId
   - accountName
  transaction: 
   - transctionId
   - transctionName
   - transctionDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your application.yml:

```
kv:
  movement:
      - accountId
      - positionId
      - accountName
  transaction:
      - transctionId
      - transctionName
      - transctionDate
```

Create a configuration class like this :

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class TestConfig {

    private Map<String,List<String>> kv;

    public Map<String, List<String>> getKv() {
        return kv;
    }

    public void setKv(Map<String, List<String>> kv) {
        this.kv = kv;
    }
}
```

Then inject TestConfig instance as

```
@Autowired
private TestConfig testConfig;
```

and retrive your key pair values like this :

```
Map<String,List<String>> kvs = testConfig.getKv();
List<String> listMovement = kvs.get("movement");
List<String> listTransaction = kvs.get("transaction");
```